# CSS : Change angle of rotation of needle

Tags: html, css

I have one image. On that image I placed one needle image and I want to rotate it at certain angle. Everything is working perfectly. What I want is to change the 0 Degree position of the needle. Currently It is at top, I want to make 0 degree point at bottom. Please see below attached image.
[image]

Here is the code I have written for this:
HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tachometer">
      <div class="needle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tachometer {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  background-image: url('../img/tachometer.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.needle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url('../img/needle.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 35px;
  left: 8%;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  transform-origin: 29% 70%;
  transform-style: preserve-3D;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

I don't know what I am missing to make this change. Please suggest.

I will change value of `transform: rotate(0deg);` of `.needle` at run time based on data.

Comment: Maybe this `transform: rotate(0deg);` should be `transform: rotate(180deg);`

Comment: Could you update with a snippet and also make your svg available

Comment: @LGSon, what should I update in snippet and how I can make svg available?

Comment: If you add your code to a snippet and upload the svg as an image in your question, you can then reference it in the snippets image url, like `url(http://i.stack.imgur.com/eBgcJ.png)`

Comment: @IsmailFarooq, yes you are right. I want to start moving needle from bottom when I will increase the angle. Currently It is moving from top to bottom.

Comment: One solution I found is that transform: rotate(0deg); start from -180 deg and keep adding my value to -180deg. Needle will move from bottom to top. For example, I want to rotate needle by 60deg. I will do: -180-60 = -240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found is that `transform: rotate(0deg);` start from -180deg and keep adding my value to -180deg. Needle will move from bottom to top. For example, I want to rotate needle by 60deg. I will do: -180-60 = -240

This is work around.

Answer (score 3):

In order to create a dial, you could use something like the below CSS to generate the circular shape. You could then rotate the `.inner` the degree amount you wish.

<sup>Within this demo, hover the circle to see a 360 rotation</sup>

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.needle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 3s;
}
.needle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  height: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  background: black;
}
.needle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  left: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}
.outer:hover .needle {
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="needle"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Slight Alteration**

If you're looking to give a degree value between 0 and 360, you could alter your CSS slightly in order to rotate from 0.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
.needle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 3s;
}
.needle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  height: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  background: black;
}
.needle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}
.outer:hover .needle {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="needle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very good solution but my requirement is different. This answer will help someone for sure. I am up-voting this but not accepting the answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi @VicJordan Could you possibly expand your requirement? This solution points to the bottom, and rotates anti-clockwise?

Comment: My requirement is rotate needle anti-clockiwse in my existing code. I have posted my solution as an answer. Please check

Comment: @VicJordan if you want to check my *'Slight Alteration'* solution, you would only need to add your value to a rotation, reducing your calculations . Glad you got sorted anyway.

Comment: thank you very much. Hope I will use this solution sometime in near future. Thank you again. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Add **`-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); transform: rotate(180deg);`** property on parent div **`.tachometer`**. I think it's work.

Comment: This will not work. As I don't want to change position of .tachometer

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tachometer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 450px;
  background-image: url('http://speedhut.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/GL2-TACH-07/GL2-TACH-07_STANDARD-000000.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}

.needle {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 45%;
  bottom: 250px;
}

.arrow {
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  transform-origin: 29% 70%;
  transform-style: preserve-3D;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tachometer">
      <div class="needle">
        <img class="arrow" src=" https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/193053/arrow-up.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is a working snippet.. try changing your rotate property to 180 from 0